# angularjs: How can I use ng-model dynamic in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use dynamic ng-model for multilingual data entry. Here is my tabset:

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="language in languages" heading="{{language}}">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name[language]" id="name[language]" class="form-control" >
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

But it gives error. How can I use it?

Here is the plunker:

[Plunker Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/sXI0ylDrAHgmGxF6nDc1?p=preview)

Comment: can you please create plunker?

Comment: Is data-ng-model an angular directive? I thought all angular directives were prefixed with ng? Wouldn't it just be ng-model?

Comment: @pje, the `data-` is an `html5` prefix for attributes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: @pje I use it to make sure that my code validates.

Comment: declaring $scope.name = [] seems to work?

Comment: @licancabur, yes, $scope.name = {}, not [], but yeah, it's working. Check my answer with a matching plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about declaring $scope.name as an empty object? It seems like it makes the error [disappear](http://plnkr.co/edit/GpHO5QPg4JWeY0RZyxHv).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an empty array in your controller as:

```
$scope.value=[];
```

In your html page you can write this:

```
<tabset>
<tab ng-repeat="language in languages" heading="{{language}}">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model=value[$index] id="value[$index]" class="form-control" >
</tab>
```